# VBA excel: Copy specific cells and columns from multiple files

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a specific cell and 3 columns from multiple files into a single column on another spreadsheet.

The part called "import" simply allows to select multiple files. The part "Datacopy" should copy the desired values.

```
Sub import()
Dim oFileDialog As FileDialog

    Set oFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    oFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = True
    oFileDialog.InitialFileName = "C:\Users\L18938\Desktop\New_folder"    ' can set your default directory here

    oFileDialog.Show

    Dim iCount As Integer
    For iCount = 1 To oFileDialog.SelectedItems.Count
        Call Datacopy(oFileDialog.SelectedItems(iCount))
    Next

End Sub

Public Function Datacopy(strPath As String)
Dim filePath As String
Dim FileNum As Integer

filePath = strPath

Dim startDate As String
If Range("A2").Value <> "" Then
    Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
Else:
    Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Offset(1, 0).Select
End If
currentRow = 0
rowNumber = 0

Open filePath For Input As #1

'EOF(1) checks for the end of a file
Do Until EOF(1)
   
        If rowNumber = 0 Then
            startDate = lineitems(2)
        End If
        If rowNumber > 18 And item <> "" Then
      
                ActiveCell.Offset(currentRow, 0) = startDate
                ActiveCell.Offset(currentRow, 1) = lineitems(0)
                ActiveCell.Offset(currentRow, 2) = lineitems(1)
                ActiveCell.Offset(currentRow, 3) = lineitems(2)
                  
                currentRow = currentRow + 1
            End If
        End If
   
    Next item
 rowNumber = rowNumber + 1
Loop
Close #1

End Function
```

When I run it I get the error "sub or function not defined".
The cells I am targeting are:

- C1 -> is a date, different in each file, to be copied in column A
- Columns A18:A, B18:B, C18:C -> are data to be copied in columns B, C, D respectively.

It is important to copy multiple files, as I have more than 180.

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: What line are you getting the error on? Is it `Open filePath For Input As #1` because that looks like it should be a comment

Comment: `Public Function Datacopy(strPath As String) `  by the way there is also a part where calls "item" that probably will gives error as it not defined (the code comes from another work)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is "startDate = lineitems(2)".  There's nothing in your code that assigns any kind of value to "lineitems".

Comment: That makes sense...it used to be in the part I have deleted because I was using this code to to the same job over csv files, but this is a normal xlsx, so I deleted the part where it split for commas.

Comment: No, I have used another code that suited for xlsx files instead of csv :)